# T-SQL How do I rollup transactions based on if a field value exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, common-table-expression

I'm using SQL Server 2014.  I have a list of financial transactions like in the below table:

```
PropertyID    OccupancyNumber    TransCode   TransDesc       VATCode    Date        Amount
1234              1111             GRNT      Garage Rent      GVAT      24/01/20    10.00
1234              1111             GVAT      Garage VAT                 24/01/20     2.00
1234              1111             RENT      RENT                       24/01/20    20.00 
1234              1111             AMEN      Amenity Charge   AVAT      23/01/20    100.00
1234              1111             AVAT      Amenity VAT                23/01/20     20.00
4567              2222             GRNT      Garage Rent      GVAT      24/01/20    15.00
4567              2222             GVAT      Garage VAT                 24/01/20     3.00
4567              2222             RENT      RENT                       24/01/20    150.00 
4567              2222             AMEN      Amenity Charge   AVAT      23/01/20    200.00
4567              2222             AVAT      Amenity VAT                23/01/20     40.00
```

However, I need to roll them up.  If there is a VATCode against a TransCode, I need to add it to the original TransCode and remove the VAT one.

Any VAT charges occur on the same day as the related Transaction.
Also, this is per OccupancyNumber

This is the desired outcome:

```
PropertyID    OccupancyNumber    TransCode   TransDesc       VATCode    Date        Amount
1234              1111             GRNT      Garage Rent      GVAT      24/01/20    12.00
1234              1111             RENT      RENT                       24/01/20    20.00 
1234              1111             AMEN      Amenity Charge   AVAT      23/01/20    120.00
4567              2222             GRNT      Garage Rent      GVAT      24/01/20    18.00
4567              2222             RENT      RENT                       24/01/20    150.00 
4567              2222             AMEN      Amenity Charge   AVAT      23/01/20    240.00
```

How would I achieve this?  Is a CTE the way to go?

Thanks.

Comment: I am unclear on the consolidation rule. For example, how can we tell that the amount on the second row should be added to the first row and not to the third row, while all have the same PropertyId, OccupancyNumber and Date?

Comment: @GMB Some of the TransCode have a related VATCode e.g. we can see on 24/01/20 GRNT is related GVAT via the VATCode field - does this help?

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use a self referencing `JOIN` and filter out the VAT transactions in the intial data set from Your Table.

This guesses the `ON` clause, but should be enough to get you there if it's not quite right:

```
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT V.PropertyID,
           V.OccupancyNumber,
           V.TransCode,
           V.TransDesc,
           NULLIF(V.VATCode,'') AS VATCode,
           TRY_CONVERT(date,V.[Date],3) AS [Date], --I hope [date] isn't a varchar, considering you display it in the format dd/MM/yy
           V.Amount
    FROM (VALUES(1234,1111,'GRNT','GarageRent','GVAT','24/01/20',10.00),
                (1234,1111,'GVAT','GarageVAT','','24/01/20',2.00),
                (1234,1111,'RENT','RENT','','24/01/20',20.00),
                (1234,1111,'AMEN','AmenityCharge','AVAT','23/01/20',100.00),
                (1234,1111,'AVAT','AmenityVAT','','23/01/20',20.00),
                (4567,2222,'GRNT','GarageRent','GVAT','24/01/20',15.00),
                (4567,2222,'GVAT','GarageVAT','','24/01/20',3.00),
                (4567,2222,'RENT','RENT','','24/01/20',150.00),
                (4567,2222,'AMEN','AmenityCharge','AVAT','23/01/20',200.00),
                (4567,2222,'AVAT','AmenityVAT','','23/01/20',40.00))V(PropertyID,OccupancyNumber,TransCode,TransDesc,VATCode,[Date],Amount))
SELECT YT.PropertyID,
       YT.OccupancyNumber,
       YT.TransCode,
       YT.TransDesc,
       YT.VATCode,
       YT.[Date],
       YT.Amount + ISNULL(VAT.Amount,0) AS Amount
FROM YourTable YT
     LEFT JOIN YourTable VAT ON YT.PropertyID = VAT.PropertyID
                            AND YT.VATCode = VAT.TransCode
WHERE YT.TransCode NOT LIKE '_VAT';
```